# POST http://localhost:5000/chatbot/ 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: mern, openai-api

I'm working on project stackoverflow clone and i tried integrating chatgpt api in my chatbot to answer doubts.

This is my index.js for server side

```js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import colors from 'colors'
import userRoutes from "./routes/Users.js";
import questionRoutes from "./routes/Questions.js";
import answerRoutes from "./routes/Answers.js";
import chatbotRoutes from "./routes/Chatbot.js";
import connectDB from './config/connectDB.js'
import otpRoutes from './routes/Otp.js'

dotenv.config()
connectDB()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.use("/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/questions", questionRoutes);
app.use("/answer", answerRoutes);
app.use("/chatbot", chatbotRoutes)
app.use('/otp', otpRoutes)


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is a stack overflow clone's API by shaurya")
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`.bgBlue.white)
})
```

This is my client side code for chatbot.jsx

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const chatLogNew = [...chatLog, { user: 'me', message: `${input}` }]
    setInput('')
    setChatLog(chatLogNew)
    const messages = chatLogNew.map(message => message.message).join('\n')
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/chatbot/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: messages
        })
      })
      const data = await response.json()
      setChatLog([...chatLogNew, { user: 'gpt', message: `${data.message}` }])
    } catch (error) {
      setChatLog([...chatLogNew, { user: 'gpt', message: 'Some error occurred. Try another question' }])
    }
  }
```

this is my server side code

chatbot.js for route

```
import express from 'express'
import { chatbotController } from '../controllers/chatbot.js'

const router = express.Router()

router.post('/',  chatbotController)

export default router
```

this is my controller for chatbot.js

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config()
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai'
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPEN_AI_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export const chatbotController = async (req, res) => {
  const { message } = req.body
  try {
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: `${message}`,
      max_tokens: 100,
      temperature: 0,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      message: response.data.choices[0].text
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(400).json("Something went wrong...")
  }
}
```

in console it is showing me this error :
Chatbot.jsx:23     POST http://localhost:5000/chatbot/ 400 (Bad Request)

i tried checking response on postman.
it gives output : something went wrong

Comment: Both 400 status code and "Something went wrong" is your own text. In the console where Express is running, `console.log(error)` will show the error that OpenAIApi is returning. List of errors for that can be found at https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes

Comment: thanks , resolved it. it was status code 429.  and after checking my usage. i found out my api was expired.